# Converting d MMMM yyyy h:mm:ss + CET OR CEST in Azure Data Factory

Tags: c#, azure, azure-data-factory

I am moving data from Blob to SQL, for the Blob I need to provide the correct schema including culture/format for datetime values (culture = 'nl-nl'):

- 17 mei 2018 10:08:44 CEST
- 10 december 2018 11:44:54 CET

I have the first part of the format string: d MMMM yyyy h:mm:ss

I am stuck with the last part of the format string.

In ADF I am not able to provide an array of formats like in C#. I am not interested in the timezone, I only need dates. How can I provide a valid format string for ADF? Are there wildcard characters available to just ignore the timezone?

Comment: Can you please specify what is input and expected date you need in this case ?

Comment: Input for example: 10 december 2018 11:44:54 CET (also CEST time). Expected output is Azure Data Factory being able to insert the datetime into a datetime field in SQL server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searched the supported [expression and functions](http://%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions) in ADF,no such features could convert `culture/format` to `datetime` format directly.

I provide two workarounds for you:

1.Create a Http Trigger Azure Function and set the convert method with c# code in it. Then use Azure Function Activity in ADF to execute the Azure Function, pass the blob storage data as input parameters.Then access the output data to the sql server sink.

2.Follow these steps to create a tempory table to receive data from blob storage and convert the format in a sql server stored procedure. You could refer to my previous case:[Azure Data Factory mapping 2 columns in one column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51352725/azure-data-factory-mapping-2-columns-in-one-column/51354266#51354266)

Comment: Thanks for your input and provided workarounds. In the mean time I came up with a 3rd workaround using a computed (persisted) column in SQL to do the required conversions.