# Azure Data Factory: Whitespace in object name for hierarchial schema mapping

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am using a Copy Data activity to copy data from a REST service to an Azure SQL Server. The REST service is returning a hierarchical JSON response and I am using schema mapping to push it into the SQL table. This is working as expected except for a few attributes that have whitespace in their name. Here is an example schema mapping with the last attribute defined the one in question:

```
"translator": {
    "type": "TabularTranslator",
    "schemaMapping": {
        "id": "id",
        "type": "type",
        "lead_verb": "lead_verb",
        "lead_action_performed": "lead_action_performed",
        "created_at": "created_at",
        "lead_id": "lead_id",
        "selected_action": "selected_action",
        "rate_type": "rate_type",
        "channel_rate_id": "channel_rate_id",
        "tenant_id": "tenant_id",
        "unit_id": "unit_id",
        "created_by_id": "created_by_id",
        "source_id": "source_id",
        "lead_changes_humanized.Quoted Rate[1]": "lead_changes_humanized"
    },
    "collectionReference": "$.lead_events"
}
```

This results in the following error:

```
{
    "errorCode": "2200",
    "message": "ErrorCode=UserErrorInvalidJsonArrayPathDefinition,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Error occurred when deserializing source JSON data. Please check whether the JsonPath in JsonNodeReference and JsonPathDefintion is valid.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common,''Type=Newtonsoft.Json.JsonException,Message=Unexpected character while parsing path:  ,Source=Newtonsoft.Json,'",
    "failureType": "UserError",
    "target": "cpyCompaniesLeadEvents"
}
```

I have tried quoting path as follows:

```
"lead_changes_humanized.\"Quoted Rate\"[1]": "lead_changes_humanized"
```

And, with single quotes:

```
"lead_changes_humanized.'Quoted Rate'[1]": "lead_changes_humanized"
```

These all result in the same error. I have validated the JSON path using path validator.

Question: how can I deal with this whitespace?

Answer (score 0):

Tried but failed to skip the copy activity validator. Please consider a workaround as below.

1.If you could totally control the rest api (named A)output,try to return `lead_changes_humanized.Quoted Rate[1]` as `lead_changes_humanized.Quoted_Rate[1]`.If you can't,create another your own rest api(named B) and invoke the A rest api inside B rest api,then process the output as `lead_changes_humanized.Quoted_Rate[1]`.

2.Then you could skip the validator with this trick.If you do concern the original format of the json key,please do the next step.

3.On the sql db side,you could copy the data from source data to the temporary table.And restore the original format in the stored procedure so that you could store the original format into the exact destination table.There are very detailed steps i did in my previous case: [Azure Data Factory mapping 2 columns in one column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51352725/azure-data-factory-mapping-2-columns-in-one-column/51354266#51354266,please) refer to it.

Comment: I do not control the API. I could, in theory, wrap the original API with another - such as an Azure Function. However, that seems like it defeats the purpose of using data factory. If I am going to write code to read the API I might as well just write code to insert it into the database. In the end, does your response mean that whitespace in the object names is not supported?