# Sink stored procedure table name is required

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I am copying data from a SQL table to another one. The sink has a stored procedure which in which a SQL Merge is done. The stored procedure has been tested directly and I can confirm that it works. I also have several different copy-activities with the same logic.

However, for 2 of them, I keep getting the following `Factory Validation Output` error.

> Sink stored procedure table name is required

Any idea where this might come from?

Here the type and procedure:

```sql
-- create type
create type [sta].[my_type] as table (
    [column1] [nvarchar](255) null,
    [column2] [nvarchar](255) null,
    [column3] [nvarchar](255) null,
    [column4] [nvarchar](255) null,
    [column5] [nvarchar](255) null,
    [column6] [nvarchar](255) null
)
GO

-- create procedure
create procedure [cdw].[sp_load_table] 
    @mytable [sta].[my_type] readonly
as
begin
    merge [cdw].[mytable] as target
    -- handle duplicates
    using (select distinct * from @mytable) as source
    on (target.[column1] = source.[column1]
        and target.[column2] = source.[column2]
        and target.[column3] = source.[column3]
        and target.[column4] = source.[column4]
        and target.[column5] = source.[column5]
        and target.[column6] = source.[column6])

    when matched and (
           COALESCE(target.[column1], 1) <> COALESCE(source.[column1], 1)
        or COALESCE(target.[column2], 1) <> COALESCE(source.[column2], 1)
        or COALESCE(target.[column3], 1) <> COALESCE(source.[column3], 1)
        or COALESCE(target.[column4], 1) <> COALESCE(source.[column4], 1)
        or COALESCE(target.[column5], 1) <> COALESCE(source.[column5], 1)
        or COALESCE(target.[column6], 1) <> COALESCE(source.[column6], 1)) then

        update 
            set target.[column1] = source.[column1],
                target.[column2] = source.[column2],
                target.[column3] = source.[column3],
                target.[column4] = source.[column4],
                target.[column5] = source.[column5],
                target.[column6] = source.[column6]

    when not matched by target
       then 
          insert ([column1], [column2], [column3], [column4], [column5], [column6])
          values (source.[column1], source.[column2], source.[column3],
                  source.[column4], source.[column5], source.[column6])

    when not matched by source
        then delete;     
end
```

And here the ADF activity:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have started a discussion on github regarding the same problem as well. It seems to be a bug at the moment. Following workaround worked for me.

Follow the discussion on Github for further info:

Github link: github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/36916

[image]

The problem has now been fixed by the Microsoft Product team. It was a bug.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you could try to adjust the value of Table type, replace `[sta].[my_type]` with `my_type`.

Please see my previous case:[Azure Data Factory mapping 2 columns in one column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51352725/azure-data-factory-mapping-2-columns-in-one-column/51354266#51354266,please) or [official example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-sql-server#invoke-a-stored-procedure-from-a-sql-sink).

[image]

Comment: Thanks but that wouldn't work, since in my case the type is in another schema and not in dbo. That's why i have to mention it. Plus, as i was saying, they all work except for two.

Comment: @COR So,any differences between 2 with others?

Comment: As I stated in my description, they're very alike. The problem seems to be very deep. I opened a ticket on github: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/36916