# Concatenate values from 2 or more columns in a csv to single column in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

In Azure Data Factory v2 (via the Azure Portal), I'm using a csv file as my source file, and an Azure SQL Server table as the destination. How in ADF can I concatenate the values of 3 columns from the csv file into one field in the database table?  It's only giving me options for 1-to-1 column mapping.  Is a Data Flow element needed for this, or can it all be done inside a Copy Data pipeline?

FYI: this is *not* the answer to my question: [Azure Data Factory mapping 2 columns in one column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51352725/azure-data-factory-mapping-2-columns-in-one-column)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Azure [Data Flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-data-flow-overview) Derived Column can help you concatenate the values of 3 columns from the csv file into one field in the database table.

You can reference my example.

**My CSV data**:

[image]

**Create a mapping Data Flow in pipeline**: set the csv file as `Source`+ `DerivedColun`+ `Sink`:

[image]

**Derived Column**: create a Visual Expression to concatenate the values of 3 columns from the csv file.
[image]

I concatenate '`b`','`c`','`d`' columns to '`b`':
[image]

**Sink Mapping settings:** choose the Derived Column instead of the column `b`
[image]

**Data Preivew:** check the data will insert to my SQL database, and run the pipeline.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Fantastic.  Thank you for the detail and screenshots.